# How to initialise @State variables depending on each other in Swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to assign my `MultilineTextField` view (a wrapped UITextView) to a variable `textField` in order to be able later to call its method `updateTextStyle` from a button in ContentView (the method takes the selected text and turns it into bold). The problem is that MultilineTextField rely on the `@State var range`, therefore not compiling. What are possible workaround for this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var range: NSRange?
@State var textField = MultilineTextField(rangeSelected: $range)

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        textField
        Button(action: {
            self.textField.updateTextStyle()
        }) {
            Text("Update text style")
        }
    }
}
```

}

In case relevant, MultilineTextField (I tried to remove the unnecessary - hope it's clear)

```
struct MultilineTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    let textView = UITextView()

    @Binding var rangeSelected: NSRange?
    @State var attributedNoteText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Lorem ipsum")

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        // ...
    
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.attributedText = attributedNoteText
    }
    
    func updateTextStyle() {
        if self.rangeSelected != nil {
            // apply attributes (makes the selected text bold)
        } else {
            print("rangeSelected is nil")
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self, $attributedNoteText)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent: MultilineTextField
        var text: Binding<NSMutableAttributedString>
        
        init(parent: MultilineTextField, _ text: Binding<NSMutableAttributedString>) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.text = text
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            let attributedStringCopy = textView.attributedText?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
            parent.textView.attributedText = attributedStringCopy
            self.text.wrappedValue = attributedStringCopy
        }
        
        func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
            parent.rangeSelected = textView.selectedRange // not sure about this one
        }   
    }
}
```

(I'm aware there might be some additional errors here - it's my first time working with UIKit in SwiftUI. Thanks for any help)

Comment: Would you mind posting `MultilineTextField` for further assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be differently, because view is struct, so your call `updateTextStyle()` in button action will have no effect, because applied to *copy* of above `textField`

Instead the approach should be like following (scratchy)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var range: NSRange?

    // example of style, on place of color your style
    @State var color: Color = .black
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MultilineTextField(rangeSelected: $range)
                .foregroundColor(self.color)          // style state dependency
            Button(action: {
                self.color = .red     // specify new style
            }) {
                Text("Update text style")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added additional information to clarify the desired behaviour. The issue in my case is that I'm trying to access the selected text from the MultilineTextField Coordinator and pass it into the struct method to change the attributed text in the view, therefore is not something I can set from ContentView